# Node JS request cookie jar missing cookies on domain change

Tags: node.js, request

I am using npm request module to send multiple requests in a session. One of these requests uses the sites mobile domain, m.example.com, rather than www.example.com

At the start of the code, I set cookie jar variable

`this.cookieJar = request.jar()`

No problem. I make a series of requests on www.example.com and they work fine.

Each request has

`jar: this.cookieJar` in the options.

But when I make a request to the mobile domain, m.example.com, all of the cookies from www.example.com disappear. I've tried setting the jar idx to mobile endpoint and that's not working either, i.e.

`this.cookieJar._jar.store.idx['m.example.com'] = this.cookieJar._jar.store.idx['www.example.com'];`

When I run the requests through Charles, all of the cookies are passed as they should up to the mobile request, where they disappear. When I try to make a request to httpbin.org/get, they don't show up. When I log to console before making the request, they show they are still in the jar.

Why is switching to the mobile endpoint not passing the cookies? What's a solution? Again I'm using npm request module + storing the cookies in a variable cookieJar.

Comment: Is the main domain setting the cookies in a way that makes them valid for the subdomain as well in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe Yes I believe so. What would be the root cause of the cookies not even being passed due to a domain change?